# Equivalent to Java import static in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a novice at Ruby and I want to know is there something equivalent to Java static import in Ruby?

```
def any_weekday
    return DateFixture.mar(21, 2014)
    // how can I use mar(21, 2014) instead?
end
```

In java, I could achieve this by using static import:

```
import static somepackage.DateFixture.mar;

private Date anyWeekda() {
    return mar(21, 2014);
}
```

I googled around but find nothing, is there other mechanism?

Comment: Something along those lines are the `include` and `extend` methods in `Module`. Google those and you will find a lot of examples on how they work.

Comment: @Casper Really thanks, I find a solution.

Comment: can't understand why this question was downvoted two times without a comment

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution inspired by @Casper's comment. It seems static method is not the right way to handle this in ruby. Module and include/extend work well in this case:

```
module DateFixture

    def mar(day, year)
        return Date.new(year, 3, day)
    end
end

class SomeTest
    include DateFixture
    def any_weekday
        return mar(21, 2014)
    end
end
```